# What is the distribution of $Y_n$ and its convergency

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X_n$ be an i.i.d. sequence of Poisson random variables with parameter $1$. Define $Y_0 = 1$ and $Y_n := X_nY_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. **How to show that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely, please?** I think it is helpful to know the distribution of $Y_n$. However, how to find this out, please? Thank you!

Comment: Once $X_n=0$ for a particular $n$, we will have $Y_k=0$ for all $k\geq n$.

Comment: @Michael: you're right I understand my error. For some reason that I don't know I was convinced that $E[Y_n^2]=1$ but actually we have $E[Y_n^2]=2^n$ so that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems#Discrete-time_results is not applicable. Thank you for your patience! I will cancel my previous comments for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

$Y_n$ has integers values, and is not zero if and only if $X_i\neq 0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. The probability $\Pr\{X_i\neq 0\}$ is $1-e^{-1}$ hence by independence, $$\Pr\{Y_n\neq 0\}=\left(1-e^{-1}\right)^n$$
from which it follows that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\{Y_n\neq 0\}\lt \infty$. The Borel-Cantelli lemma allows to conclude.